# Deserialize into different implementors of trait with serde?

Tags: rust, yaml, deserialization, serde

I am trying to deserialize a YAML config file in Rust using the Serde library. On many places, the format uses a convention of drivers, i.e. a field named "driver" determines what kind of object the configuration is for. For example, this would be two valid configurations:

```yaml
reader:
  driver: file
  path: /var/log/foo
```

```yaml
reader:
  driver: http
  port: 8080
  endpoint: /api/bar
```

I have the following structs that I want to deserialize into:

```
struct Settings {
    reader: Reader,
}

trait Reader {}

struct FileReader {
    path: String,
}

impl Reader for FileReader {}

struct HttpReader {
    port: u32,
    endpoint: String,
}

impl Reader for HttpReader {}
```

Is there any way I can instruct Serde to deserialize into these structs, preferably without having to do the implementation myself? Can I somehow modify my structs to make them easier to deserialize into, perhaps by introducing an enum or something?

Comment: See also [How can deserialization of polymorphic trait objects be added in Rust if at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/155423)