# How do I use a variable as the data type for a different variable?

Tags: variables, rust

If I have the data type of something stored in the variable `data_type`, how can I create a new variable with the data type defined in this variable?

For example:

```rust
struct a {
    var: String,
}
struct b {
    var: String,
}

let var_type = "a";
let variable: var_type { var: "abc" };  // creates struct var_type
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231020/how-can-deserialization-of-polymorphic-trait-objects-be-added-in-rust-if-at-all

Comment: You might want to look at Serde. Serialization / deserialization has similar problem space to your question -- https://serde.rs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Isak van Bakel, most said  rust is static. However, if you have a list of  all the possible structures, you can. (assuming your using serde here!). There is currently 
a interesting question discussing polymorphic de-serialisation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231020/how-can-deserialization-of-polymorphic-trait-objects-be-added-in-rust-if-at-all),  i suggest you take a look as it may help!

Comment: Thank you.  That post is exactly what i have been looking for!!

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 4):

As long as you know all of your types at compile time, it is possible to transform unstructured data into typed data based on some value in the data.  This is exactly what is done by the popular [serde crate](https://serde.rs/)

Without knowing the use case, it's difficult to address the question precisely, yet the code below gives two examples about how to accomplish type-mapping using an enum (though match could be used to map any data to any type that is known at compile time).

```
enum VarType {
    A(String),
    B(String),
    Unknown(String),
}

fn main() {
    let _var1 = VarType::A("abc".to_string());
    let _var2 = VarType::B("xyz".to_string());

    let data = vec![("a", "abc"), ("b", "xyz")];

    for item in data {
        let (data_type, value) = item;
        match data_type {
            "a" => VarType::A(value.to_string()),
            "b" => VarType::B(value.to_string()),
            _ => VarType::Unknown(value.to_string()),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contributions however that sadly does not fit my use case.

Comment: @ArielHurdle can you describe how this is different from your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Rust is statically typed.