# How do I create a generic struct that can be serialized with Serde and retain type information?

Tags: generics, serialization, rust, traits, serde

I want to use Serde to serialize a data structure that is generic.

The users of my library should be able to provide their own structure that implements `Serialize` and `Deserialize`. I should be able to get back the original type information for the value that they serialized the data with.

How would I go about doing this?

I have tried something like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Message<V> {
    key: Key,
    value: V,
}
```

I want to get back the type of `V` after I deserialize the data.

Is this the way to do it or am I way off track?

I want the user to be able to extend the possible values/types. I want the behavior of enums, but flexibility for the user to add their own structs as possible candidates. Similar to [this code](https://github.com/jaysonsantos/bmemcached-rs/blob/ea627ee3456f73d39c7097b1f1647039bc74f27f/src/protocol.rs) but they all need unique *ids*.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://serde.rs/attr-bound.html

Comment: @SørenMortensen I think it's kind of similar to what I'm after but I want the user to provide the de-serialize for the value and the possibility to pass different types of my generic.

Comment: @SørenMortensen, or maybe better than I tough initially. But can it keep track of what type I used? Or do I need to tell rust what types like this `Outer<u64, str>` or can they be inferred?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167836/discussion-between-drpytho-and-shepmaster).

Comment: Does [How do I deserialize into trait, not a concrete type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42392935/155423) or [How can deserialization of polymorphic trait objects be added in Rust if at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/155423) provide information / answer your question?

Comment: Close. That was what I first thought of, but I want the user to be able to extend the values/types possible. I want the behavior of enums, but flexibility for the user to add their own structs as possible candidates. Similar to [this code](https://github.com/jaysonsantos/bmemcached-rs/blob/ea627ee3456f73d39c7097b1f1647039bc74f27f/src/protocol.rs) but they all need unique *ids*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is completely impossible in the general sense.

Each type is able to control its own serialization. That means that multiple types could end up serializing to *the same value*:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Age(i32);

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Weight(i32);

fn main() {
    let a = Age(42);
    let a_str = serde_json::to_string(&a).unwrap();
    println!("{}", a_str); // 42
    let b: Weight = serde_json::from_str(&a_str).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

You could try to build up markers inside the serialized data that identify the type, but ultimately the same problem occurs: there's always the possibility for conflicts.

Even more fundamentally, such a concept isn't valid in Rust where each type has to have a known size at compile time. There's no way to deserialize into a variable of *unknown size*.

Equally fundamentally, what type would you provide for the generic `V`? You can't "forget" to specify all generic types when you compile your code.

Because of this, usually such a thing doesn't even come up. If the user calls your serialization code with a concrete type, they can call your deserialization code with the same concrete type.

> I want the behavior of enums, but flexibility for the user to add their own structs.

That sounds like a *trait object*.

See also:

- [How do I deserialize into trait, not a concrete type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42392935/155423)
- [How can deserialization of polymorphic trait objects be added in Rust if at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/155423)

Answer (score 0):

the best way of implementing such a think would be to restrict the type of V, then use the structs name as a means of identifying the type+string for module maybe.

Example

```
pub struct Message<V: Serialize + Deserialize> {
     key: keytype,
     value: V,
     crate_path: String
}
```

then use something like sha to generate a hash for the struct name, Deserialize to check the struct name.