# Why do I get an UnsupportedType error when serializing to TOML with a manually implemented Serialize for an enum with struct variants?

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

I'm trying to implement `Serialize` for an enum that includes struct variants. The [serde.rs documentation](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html#serializing-an-enum) indicates the following:

```
enum E {
    // Use three-step process:
    //   1. serialize_struct_variant
    //   2. serialize_field
    //   3. end
    Color { r: u8, g: u8, b: u8 },

    // Use three-step process:
    //   1. serialize_tuple_variant
    //   2. serialize_field
    //   3. end
    Point2D(f64, f64),

    // Use serialize_newtype_variant.
    Inches(u64),

    // Use serialize_unit_variant.
    Instance,
}
```

With that in mind, I proceeded to implemention:

```
use serde::ser::{Serialize, SerializeStructVariant, Serializer};
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum Variants {
    VariantA,
    VariantB { k: u32, p: f64 },
}

impl Serialize for Variants {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match *self {
            Variants::VariantA => serializer.serialize_unit_variant("Variants", 0, "VariantA"),
            Variants::VariantB { ref k, ref p } => {
                let mut state =
                    serializer.serialize_struct_variant("Variants", 1, "VariantB", 2)?;
                state.serialize_field("k", k)?;
                state.serialize_field("p", p)?;
                state.end()
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Variants::VariantB { k: 5, p: 5.0 };
    let toml_str = toml::to_string(&x).unwrap();
    println!("{}", toml_str);
}
```

The code compiles, but when I run it it fails:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: UnsupportedType', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

I figured the issue must be in my use of the API, so I consulted the API [documentation for `StructVariant`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_struct_variant) and it looks practically the same as my code. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't see it based on the docs and output.

Comment: What prevents you from deriving `Serialize` like most usages?

Comment: It fails with the same error "value: UnsupportedType". Presumably, my implementation is doing exactly the same that serde_derive would do? In which case, some advice on what the right thing to do would be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your question to show what you'd like the generated TOML to be?

Comment: Actually, I guess I was trying to find out what the output was going to be myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling external tagging for the enum enables Serde to serialize/deserialize it to TOML:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Variants {
    VariantA,
    VariantB { k: u32, p: f64 },
}

toml::to_string(&Variants::VariantB { k: 42, p: 13.37 })
```

serializes to

```
type = VariantB
k = 42
p = 13.37
```

This works well in `Vec`s and `HashMap`s, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to be honest I don't even remember what I was using this for (asked about a year ago) but it's good to know it can be done!

Answer (score 5):

The TOML format does not support enums with values:

```
use serde::Serialize; // 1.0.99
use toml; // 0.5.3

#[derive(Serialize)]
enum A {
    B(i32),
}

fn main() {
    match toml::to_string(&A::B(42)) {
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {}", e),
    }
}
```

```
Error: unsupported Rust type
```

It's unclear what you'd like your data structure to map to as TOML. Using JSON  works just fine:

```
use serde::Serialize; // 1.0.99
use serde_json; // 1.0.40

#[derive(Serialize)]
enum Variants {
    VariantA,
    VariantB { k: u32, p: f64 },
}

fn main() {
    match serde_json::to_string(&Variants::VariantB { k: 42, p: 42.42 }) {
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {}", e),
    }
}
```

```
{"VariantB":{"k":42,"p":42.42}}
```

Comment: It seems clear what the serialization should be:

    [VariantB]
    k: 42
    p: 42.42